# How would I find the intersection of two lists in python without using sets

Tags: python, list

I have a program with two very large lists, one with 3^12 terms and the other with 5000 terms, and I want to find the intersection of them (items that are the same in both lists).

I have already tried using sets and loops(see below).

I have tried (in Python 3)

```py
[i for i in joinedCombs if i in dictionary]
```

and

```py
endResult = list(set(joinedCombs)&set(dictionary))
```

I get a time error for the first line of code and a memory error for the second line of code. What could I do to balance out speed and time? Please leave an answer, not a comment

Comment: you have a list called `dictionary`?

Comment: The union would be the set of elements in *either* list; you want the *intersection*.

Comment: Which is the huge list, and which is the smaller list? Semantically, `[i for i in joinedCombs if i in dictionary]` and `[i for i in dictionary if i in joinedCombs]` produce the same result (ordering aside), but have wildly different running times. Also, are `joinedCombs` and `dictionary` both actual lists? Only the container used with `in` needs to be turned in to a set; iteration over a set and a list take the same amount of time, but set inclusion is *much* faster than list inclusion.

Comment: @chepner does `it = iter(lst1)` actually save memory compared to iterating over the list, i'm confusing myself

Comment: It does not; it just returns an iterator over that list. But `[i for i in lst1 ...]` would implicitly create a list iterator for you, so there's no need to create `it` explicitly.

Comment: I am looking for a solution to the memory problem, as for which is bigger, there is no definite answer, depending on the input(which the grader decides) dictionary could be larger or smaller than joinedCombs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `len` to determine which list is the shorter one, and create a set from that:

```
[i for i in joinedCombs if i in dictionary]
if len(joinedCombs) < len(dictionary):
    s1 = set(dictionary)
    itr = joinedCombs
else:
    s1 = set(joinedCombs)
    itr = dictionary

new = [i for i in itr if i in s1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this line of code :

```
endResult = list(set(joinedCombs).intersection(dictionary))
```

Comment: Thank You for this answer! However, joinedCombs might be smaller than dictionary. For this reason, I accepted the other answer.